# Find all rows in pandas-dataframe with duplicate row index

Tags: python, pandas

Assume I have a dataframe similar to:

```
          A  B
0  [ab, cd]  1
1  [cd, de]  2
2  [de, ef]  1
3      [gh]  1
```

I am now interested in finding all "duplicate" entries when splitting it up by using `.explode("A")`. Using `explode()` I get the following output:

```
    A  B
0  ab  1
0  cd  1
1  cd  2
1  de  2
2  de  1
2  ef  1
3  gh  1
```

I would like to get the position of all rows where the index is more than once (i.e. the rows with indices [0, 1, 2]). One option would be of course to iterate over all rows and check if I get multiple rows when calling `df.loc[i]`, but I could imagine this being very slow. Are there faster in-built options, ideally mapping the returned rows to the "real" row indices?

I.e. calling df.loc[0] would return

```
    A  B
0  ab  1
0  cd  1
```

and in addition to that, I would be interested in the "real" indices, here being `[0, 1]`. How could I achieve that?

Comment: Wouldn't `df[df["A"].str.len().gt(1)]` suffice here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to Jezrael's good answer, you can always use `reset_index()` and get what you call "real" index.

```
df = df.explode("A").reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'Old Index'})
```

Outputting:

```
   Old Index   A  B
0          0  ab  1
1          0  cd  1
2          1  cd  2
3          1  de  2
4          2  de  1
5          2  ef  1
6          3  gh  1
```

And you can then filter easily by using:

```
uniques = df.drop_duplicates('Old Index',keep=False)
duplicated = df.drop(uniques.index)
```

Answer (score 1):

For duplicated indices check them by [`Index.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.duplicated.html) in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df.explode("A")
#first duplicated index
idx = df1.index[df1.index.duplicated()]
print (idx)
Int64Index([0, 1, 2], dtype='int64')
```

---

```
#all duplicated index
idx = df1.index[df1.index.duplicated(keep=False)]
print (idx)
Int64Index([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2], dtype='int64')
```

If need default index values:

```
m = df1.index.duplicated(keep=False)
df2 = df1.reset_index(drop=True)
print (df2)
    A  B
0  ab  1
1  cd  1
2  cd  2
3  de  2
4  de  1
5  ef  1
6  gh  1
```

With filtering by duplicated index of `df1.index`:

```
print(df2[m])
    A  B
0  ab  1
1  cd  1
2  cd  2
3  de  2
4  de  1
5  ef  1

print(df2[~m])
    A  B
6  gh  1
```

Comment: If I call df.duplicated on my exploded dataframe, I just get a list filled with `False`, i.e. something is going wrong here...